# Discord.js: How to move user from any voice channel to a certain voice channel if they input a specific string?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm super new to discord.js and I checked their documentation but I can't seem to find any answers to this question. Here is my code so far, and what it's supposed to do is check every message, see if the message came from a bot, check if they entered the password then delete the password and move them to another voice channel.

The error I'm getting is: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [GUILD_VOICE_CHANNEL_RESOLVE]: Could not resolve channel to a guild voice channel. Can somebody please help? Thanks!

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author.bot === false) {
        if (message.content == 'password') {
            message.delete();
            message.guild.member(message.author.id).voice.setChannel('The Grind 3');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which version your using but instead of `setChannel('The Grind 3')`
you should `setChannel('channel id')` which you can get by `setting>Appearance>turn on Developer Mode` then right click the specified channel and copy id and paste it instead of
'The Grind 3' and this should do :)

Comment: tysm! I thought the .setchannel looked for the channel name!

Answer (score 0):

This is rather easy to do.

First you need to find the channel you want to use.

```
const VCchannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'The Grind 3');
```

Now you can set send the member to that voice channel. *Note: We catch the error here so that we can handle it if something is wrong.*

```
message.member.voice.setChannel(VCchannel).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Keep in mind that this only works if the member that uses this command is in a voice channel already as the bot cannot force someone to enter a voice channel.

*Note: You might want to consider checking if the member is a bot and then return if true. That has the advantage that you don't need to put your entire code inside the `if` statement.*

```
if (message.author.bot) return;
```

Your entire `onMessage` event should look a little like this.

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.content == 'password') {
        message.delete();
        const VCchannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'The Grind 3');
        message.member.voice.setChannel(VCchannel).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks! i always forget to catch the error! thanks for the suggestion about return true when checking if the author is a bot. I'm still not used to the idea that return also terminates the function!

Comment: `return` doesn't always terminate the function. See here https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_return.asp