# How to move members between channels in Discord.js V 14

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I need my Bot to move members between Channels. I recently upgraded to Discord.js Version 14 from Version 12. 
My discord.js Version: 14.7.1
My node.js Version: 18.12.1

My main.js

```
const { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits, Collection, ActivityType } = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("node:fs");
const path = require("node:path");
const { token } = require("./config.json");

const botIntents = [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates
];

const client = new Client({ intents: botIntents, partials: ["CHANNEL"] });

client.commands = new Collection();

const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, "commands");
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    if ("data" in command && "execute" in command) {
        client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
    } else {
        console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
    }
}
// Bot ready event
client.once(Events.ClientReady, (c) => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${c.user.tag}`);
    c.user.setActivity("/help", { type: ActivityType.Watching });
});
// Message input to command
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async (interaction) => {
    if (!(interaction.isChatInputCommand())) return;

    const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!(command)) {
        console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`);
        return;
    }

    try {
        
        await command.execute(interaction);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        // ephemeral: true / private message, only visible to message sender (user) 
        await interaction.reply({ content: "There was an error while executing this command!", ephemeral: true });
    }
});


client.login(token);
```

My working Code in **Version 12**.

```
module.exports = {
    name: "my_name",
    description: "my_description",
    execute(message, args) {
        const member = message.mentions.members.first();
        if (!(args[1])) {
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("my_command")
                .setColor(0x992d22)
                .setDescription("my_description")
                .setFooter(`Requested by ${message.author.tag}.`, message.author.displayAvatarURL);
            message.channel.send(embed);
        }
        if (!member) return message.reply("enter a member name.")
        if (!member.voice.channel) return message.reply("the member is not in a voice channel.");
        if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.reply("you need to join a voice channel first.");
        message.channel.send("my_message");
        member.voice.setChannel("my_channel_id");
    }
}
```

I tried to get it to work in **Version 14** like so.

```
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("my_name")
        .setDescription("my_description")
        .addUserOption((option) =>
            option
                .setName("member")
                .setDescription("my_description")
                .setRequired(true)
        )
        .setDMPermission(false),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const master = interaction.user.username;
        const target = interaction.options.getUser("member");
        const cageId = "my_channel_id";


        if (!(interaction.member.voice.channel)) {
            return await interaction.reply({ content: "You need to join a Voice-Channel first.", ephemeral: true });
        }
        if (!(target.voice.channelId)) {
            return await interaction.reply({ content: "The Member is currently not in a Voice-Channel.", ephemeral: true });
        }

        await target.voice.setChannel(cageId);

        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor(0x992d22)
            .setTitle("my_title")
            .setDescription("my_description")
            .setFooter({ text: `Requested by ${master}` })
            .setTimestamp();

        return await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
    },
}
```

Problem

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setChannel')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channelId')
```

I tried to Google it for quite some time, but i was not able to find a fitting solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js: How to move user from any voice channel to a certain voice channel if they input a specific string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64713317/discord-js-how-to-move-user-from-any-voice-channel-to-a-certain-voice-channel-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a couple of little tweaks and you should have what you're looking for.

First, make sure that when you're starting your bot you are requesting the needed Intent `GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates`. [Gateway Intents Documentation](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#gateway-intents)

Make certain that the option collected is the GuildMember:

```js
const target = interaction.options.getUser("member");
```

to

```js
const target = interaction.options.getMember("member");
```

Then when you are referencing the guild member, you need to specify that you're talking about the [VoiceState](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=voice):

```js
if (!(target.channelId)) {
```

becomes

```js
if (!(target.voice.channelId)) {
```

and

```js
await target.setChannel(cageId);
```

becomes

```js
await target.voice.setChannel(cageId);
```

Comment: target.voice seems to be undefined, i added my main.js to my question.

Comment: instead of `const target = interaction.options.getUser("member");` try `const target = interaction.options.getMember("member");` to get GuildMember instead of the base user

Comment: .getMember fixed it, tyvm.